# Get data from Serial Port and use set time in Datetime c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, pic32

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and am coding using C#.

I've programmed a clock on my pic32 and sending the data of this clock over the serial port.

I'm trying trying to put a string mydata from the serial port and put it into Datetime. But i'm getting exeptions and don't know why.

What i'm getting on my myData is like this: 00:10:2300:10:2300:10:2300:10:2300:10:2300:10:2300:10:23

Could you guys give me a heads up on this?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace klokske
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                mySerialPort.Open();
                rtRX.Text = "Port Opened";
            }
            else
                rtRX.Text = "Port busy";
        }

        DateTime dateTime;

        private void AnalogClock_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTime = DateTime.Parse(myData);
        }

              private string myData;
        private void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
                myData = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
                 this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayText));
        }

        private void displayText(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtRX.AppendText(myData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (**not** all the code you have) and ask a **specific** question. Currently, it's hard to say what you're actually asking about. Where is your specific problem?

Comment: Maybe use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Just about nobody understands how ReadExisting() works.  Which is odd, it does have an excellent name.  It returns what is *existing* in the receive buffer.  Which is about never exactly "00:10:23".  You typically get one or two characters, serial ports are slow.  Counting them off is required, always best done with Read().

Answer (score 0):

As @Hans Passant mentioned, the `ReadExisting()` only returns what is currently in the receive buffer.  The `DataReceived` event can fire randomly, so when this event is firing you may not have all the characters you are looking for yet.  You need to build a string until you have the whole message then you can display the text.

```
char ESC = (char)27;
char CR = (char)13;
char LF = (char)10;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//in my case, the data im expected is ended with a Line Feed (LF)
//so I'll key on LF before I send my message
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == LF)
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(sb.toString()));
        }
        else
        {
            //else, we append the char to our string that we are building
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```